# How to share app in social media through button click in iOS 7?

Tags: facebook, ios7, uibutton, share, social-media

I am trying to Share my app through social media. Specifically fb, but I can't share my post.

I need to tap button specifically given in my design..

I used the coding below:

```
NSString *facebookShareLink = @"http://google.com";
NSString *titleToShare = @"Title";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@", facebookShareLink]];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookShareLink]  ];

} else
{

    NSString *facebookLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsharer%2Fsharer.php%3Fu%3D%2525%2540%26t%3D%2525%2540&display=popup", facebookShareLink, titleToShare];
    facebookLink = [facebookLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookLink]];
}
```

Which is taken from StackOverflow itself..

Can anyone help me to resolve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this.. Initially add sociamedia.framework to the project. Then import  framework in class file .h or .m..

```
-(IBAction)facebookPost:(id)sender{
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock =  ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};
controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
//Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS
[controller setInitialText:@"My test post"];
//Adding the URL to the facebook post value from iOS
[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com"]];
//Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```